# Javascript : How to send uploaded email to webservice in byte array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, extjs, file-conversion

**background : My website is developed using EXTJS6.
I have a webservice which expects the uploaded email to be sent to the service in the byte array format.**

**Question :** How to I convert .msg to byte array using JS (Or EXTJS)? Can we just treat it as a binary file conversion to byte array?

Any pointers please?

Gendaful

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file input, this should work:

```
var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
var file = input.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onloadend = function(){
    // do sth with data
    console.log(fr.result);
};
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```